# Adding Custom Date Range on Admin Dashboard Chart Magento

Tags: magento-1.7, dashboard, admin-panel

I am working on a task to show Date Range on Dashboard chart. so data chart will display on custom date range selection. I have added calendar on chart but result is not coming properly. I know its very specific requirement. I am looking if someone has already done such modification and can provide me some guidence to achieve this.

I have added calendar from the following code in `adminhtml/default/default/template/dashboard/graph.phtml`:

```
<div class="field">
    <label for="startdate"><?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Start Date') ?></label>
    <div class="input-box">
        <input name="startdate" id="startdate" value="" type="text">
        <img title="Select date" id="startdate_trig" src="<?php echo 'http://192.168.0.32/pankgento/skin/adminhtml/default/default/images/grid-cal.gif'; ?>" class="v-middle">
    </div>
 </div>

 <div class="field">
    <label for="enddate"><?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('End Date') ?></label>
    <div class="input-box">
        <input name="enddate" id="enddate" value="" type="text">
        <img title="Select date" id="enddate_trig" src="<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_SKIN).'/adminhtml/default/default/images/grid-cal.gif'; ?>" class="v-middle">
    </div>
 </div>

 <div class="field">
    <div class="input-box">
        <input type="button" name="btn" value="Search" onchange="changeDiagramsPeriod();" />
    </div>
 </div>
```

Already a function `changeDiagramsPeriod` created in `adminhtml/default/default/template/dashboard/index.phtml`. It is responsible for making the ajax request, its creating ajax request for every dynamic block.

Comment: I have not done this before, but you may get some idea how to do this by following this tutorial [link](http://greladesign.com/blog/2011/06/06/modify-admin-dashboards-default-period-time-select-range/)

Comment: Can you elaborate on "so data chart will display on custom date range selection" - do you mean "so data chart will display *a* custom date range selection"?

Comment: yes I need to select start and end date. so all the sale done in that period will show in chart. like currently it happen when we select last 7days and current month option.

Comment: You say you alraedy added the calendar. Can you post your code?

Comment: @Marius .. Can you guide me little bit so that I will be able to achieve this.

Comment: @PankajPareek. I don't heave a clear vision on this. All I can tell you is that you need to modify `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Dashboard_Graph::getChartUrl` to include your new interval, and `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Dashboard_Tab_Orders::_prepareData` to support again your date range. Same for `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Dashboard_Tab_Amounts`. That's all I can think of right now.

Comment: @PankajPareek. If you find a solution to this, please post it somewhere. This looks like a really useful tool to have.

Comment: @PankajPareek Did you solve this?

Answer (score 2):

Magento filter and search date in format ,Use date php as

```
    $fromDate = date('Y-m-d'. ' 00:00:00', strtotime($fromDate));
    $toDate = date('Y-m-d'. ' 23:59:00', strtotime($toDate));
```

or javascript set like as

```
var from = new Date(year, month, day, 00, 00, 00);
var toDate = new Date(year, month, day, 23, 59, 00);
```

Comment: Adrian's solution seems the one that is working for me. Can't seem to upvote his reply though because of my low reputation (am new here).

Answer (score 0):

I have developped an extension to be able to have a 12 hours range in the dashboard.
It's available here: http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/12-hours-range-dashboard.html

I suggest you download it and you can modify it to add another custom range that would fill your needs ;)